# WPF DataGrid Left Click only on Row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, inputbinding

How can i do a leftclick on a datagrid only enable when a row is selected? 
here are a example:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding LeftClickCommand}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

Now when i click on no row in the datagrid the command is also executed, but i only wants to execute it when i click on a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can test if the selected item is null 
this is just a way that maybe help you
XAML:

```
        <Custom1:DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"  >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <Custom:EventToCommand CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=dg}" Command="{Binding AfficheCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Code behind :

```
    private PersonModel _selectedPersons = new PersonModel();
    public PersonModel SelectedPerson
    {
        set
        {
            _selectedPersons = value;
        }
    }
    public ICommand AfficheCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(AfficheText);
        }
    }

    private void AfficheText()
    {
        if(_selectedPersons != null)
           MessageBox.Show(_selectedPersons.FirstName);

       _selectedPersons  = null;
    }
```

I know that is not the best way but a way until you found a better idea ;)

Comment: this works just one time on applicationstart. because if i select on item in the datagrid the selected value is not null. and if i click on the datagrid background the selected item is also not null. can i reset it to null or something like this?

Comment: @user2025830 : you can make _selectedPersons = null when you command is done, I edit my code